# Авторизация пользователя не сразу, а после обновления страницы

Tags: wordpress, авторизация

После клика на ссылку в электронном письме для подтверждения регистрации на сайте, я планирую из открывшегося окна авторизовать пользователя:

```
...
update_user_meta($user->ID, 'is_email_confirmed', '1');
mysite_send_info_message($user->ID); //отправить письмо пользователю о подтверждении регистрации
do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $email);
wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
...
```

Но авторизация пользователя происходит не сразу, а после обновления страницы. Что нужно сделать, чтобы сразу логинить пользователя?

Comment: Ну а как вы хотели. Куки надо устанавливать ДО какого-либо вывода на страницу. Это ограничение протокола http.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, так у меня сначала идёт php, а потом вывод, т.е. текст html. И что самое непонятное, что сначала (благодаря тексту в вопросе) на странице "Ваш аккаунт подтверждён" is_user_logged_in() даёт true, затем при переходе на главную страницу сайта is_user_logged_in() становится false, а потом после F5 - true

Comment: А какой вывод происходит по wp_login?)

Comment: @KAGGDesign, в смысле? это стандартный action. и потом, я добавил его, пробуя возможные варианты решение, когда этой строки не было, баг был тот же

Comment: @KAGGDesign может быть решение отыщется, если понять, почему is_user_logged_in() сначала true, затем после редиректа на главную страницу - false, а потом, после обновления - стабильно true, мне вот это больше всего непонятно